# How to save multilanguage data in moongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

i try to learn Mean.js and i need to use multilanguage support in my app. 
 I chose this schema to save data

```
 "_id": {   
    "name": {       
        en: "English",
        fr: "Français"      
            }
      }
```

in my server model:

```
var KnowledgeSchema = new Schema({
name: {
     en: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Knowledge name',
    trim: true
        },
        fr : {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Please fill Knowledge name',
    trim: true
        }
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
   });
mongoose.model('Knowledge', KnowledgeSchema);
```

and controller

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
var knowledge = new Knowledge(req.body);
knowledge.user = req.user;

knowledge.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(knowledge);
    }
});
};
```

What i need for save "en" and "fr" into "name" ?

Comment: Firstly, is your data in the correct format? Shouldn't it be `{"_id": xxx,  "name": { en: "English",  fr: "Français"  }  }`? Secondly, can you please post the actual `req.body` data?

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by added `name: this.name`  in angular controller and `data-ng-model="name.en"`